# Frobenius automorphism for primes ramified over field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

For a Galois extension $L/K$ of algebraic number fields with rings of integers $\mathcal{O}_L$ and $\mathcal{O}_K$ respectively, a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subset \mathcal{O}_K$ unramified over $\mathcal{O}_L$, some choice of prime ideal $\mathfrak{P} \subset \mathcal{O}_L$ above $\mathfrak{p}$, and the decomposition subgroup $D_{\mathfrak{P}}<\textrm{Gal}(L/K)$, one can use the following isomorphism:
$$
D_{\mathfrak{P}} \cong \textrm{Gal}((\mathcal{O}_L/\mathfrak{P})/(\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p})) \tag{$*$}
$$
to show that there exists a unique automorphism (the Frobenius automorphism) $\varphi_{\mathfrak{P}} \in \textrm{Gal}(L/K)$ satisfying:
$$
\varphi_{\mathfrak{P}}(x) \equiv x^q\ (\textrm{mod}\ \mathfrak{P}) \quad \textrm{for all} \quad x \in \mathcal{O}_L, \tag{$\dagger$}
$$

where $q:= \lvert \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p} \rvert$ is the order of the base residue field.

This is true for all primes $\mathfrak{p} \subset \mathcal{O}_K$ unramified over $\mathcal{O}_L$.

Now I have read somewhere (E. Kowalski, *An Introduction to the Langlands Program*, p. 9) that when we have a prime $\mathfrak{p} \subset \mathcal{O}_K$ that is *ramified* over $\mathcal{O}_L$, we have not a single Frobenius element $\varphi_{\mathfrak{P}} \in \textrm{Gal}(L/K)$ satisfying $(\dagger)$, but rather a *conjugacy class* in $\textrm{Gal}(L/K)$ of such elements.

I have been trying to find resources that treat the existence of the Frobenius conjugacy class for the ramified primes, but have been unable to find any.

The problem I am having is that for ramified primes, we have not the isomorphism $(*)$, but rather:
$$
D_{\mathfrak{P}}/I_{\mathfrak{P}} \cong \textrm{Gal}((\mathcal{O}_L/\mathfrak{P})/(\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p})),
$$

where $I_{\mathfrak{P}} \vartriangleleft D_{\mathfrak{P}}$ is the (non-trivial) inertia subgroup. Hence we cannot view $\textrm{Gal}((\mathcal{O}_L/\mathfrak{P})/(\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}))$ as a subgroup of $\textrm{Gal}(L/K)$ as we can with the unramified primes.

I would much appreciate it if anyone could provide a reference to a resource that treats the Frobenius automorphism for ramified primes, or provide some guidance in resolving my difficulties.

Many thanks.

Comment: I am sorry, which are your difficulties in the ramified case? Simply, if the prime is not unramified, then the Frobenius is still an element of $D_{\mathfrak{P}}$, but only defined up to the inertia, i.e., as you said, is a class. At the moment no references in which one explicitly studies the ramified case come to my mind. However, I can give you an interesting (at least, for me) situation in which one needs to work which Frobenius without knowing if the prime is unramified.

Comment: If $K$ is a number field and $G_K$ is the Galois group of $\bar{K}/K$, then one wants to study the $G_K$-representations, i.e. free $\mathbb{Z}_p$ of finite rank $M$ on which $G_K$ acts (continuously). If we fix a prime $v$ of $k$ and we take $v'$ over $v$ in $\bar{K}$ (we can do it also if the extension is infinite), then we say that the action is unramified at $v$ if the inertia $I_{v'/v}$ acts trivially on $M$. (The inertia are conjugates, so this does not depend on the choice of $v'$).

Comment: Then one wants usually to consider the polynomial $\det(1-x\text{Fr}_{v'/v}\mid M)\in\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$. If we don't know that the prime is unramified, the Frobenius is not unique; but it is defined up to the inertia, and since this acts trivially on $M$, the polynomial is still well-defined. This is a standard situation in theory of Galois representations, with several applications in number theory.